# How to use Windows XP theme in Java/Swing applications?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have to use Windows XP theme in my Java/Swing project.
There are classes like below.

```
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
```

`WindowsLookAndFeel` can be used when someone wants to use the same theme as currently applied by the user.

```
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel
```

`WindowsClassicLookAndFeel` can be used when someone wants to specifically use the windows classic theme.

When we change a theme of Windows from XP to classic, swing UI also changes from XP to classic. How can we force it using aforementioned classes?

Comment: The whole purpose of `WindowsLookAndFeel` is to present the Swing UI exactly as a native Windows UI. So it makes perfect sense that your application automatically adapts to whatever the user chooses.

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is.  Force nothing, let the user have whatever PLAF they want!  BTW - what do the users on *nix & OS X get?

Comment: Use the second classic one. You will always have the classic style, independent to the user chosen theme.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use this line

```
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel( javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

because if you run the application in another system you could haven't windows look and feel.

or you can use this:

```
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("<lookAndFeelName>".equals(info.getName())) {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
    }
}
```

because in this way, if you want to force the windows Look and feel you should verify if this lookAndFeel exists

Or you have 2 good ways to set lookAndFeel without check if exists:

```
try {
    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    //javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    //Handle Exception
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    //Handle Exception
} catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    //Handle Exception
} catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    //Handle Exception
}
```

or simply:

```
try {
    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    //javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //Handle Exception
}
```

The difference between WindowsLookAndFeel and WindowsClassicLookAndFeel, is that "WindowsLookAndFeel" will corresponds to user Windows Theme and "WindowsClassicLookAndFeel" will force java application GUI to match Windows Classic Theme even if user has not set their Windows Theme to classic.

So you can force classic but you can't force Vista/7 LookAndFeel using Windows Classic Theme.

Or you can design your application to anything like Vista/7 LookAndFeel (just kidding)

Comment: My problem is not about getting the system look and feel. My application is meant to run only on windows and at the same time, i **don't** want it to have a look of windows classic theme, which is possible if user changes his theme. Looking for any workarounds...

Answer (score 2):

One way is to implement it in constructor:

```
public class LookS extends JFrame { 

  String win1 = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel";
  String win2 = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel";

public LookS(){
...

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(win1);
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
...
}
```

Also, you can consider these classes too:

```
  String srt1 = "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel";
  String srt2 = "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel";
  String srt3 = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel";
  String srt4 = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
```

this will get you the native look and feel

Comment: Not on *nix or OS X it won't.  It'll get you more like a `ClassNotFoundException` (fortunately).  Very poor suggestion.  -1