# Java set JFrame renderer

Tags: java, jframe, rendering, lwjgl

I want to make a java widget library rendering on LWJGL3. I was thinking, would it be possible to (instead of creating an entire widget library) set the rendering engine of a JFrame to a custom class? (I've got my reasons why I do not wish to use the default java one)

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Why not just extend and change any swing class that you want to modify?

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I'm not quite sure how the inner structure of swing classes work. Is there a specific .render() method?

I assume I could use something like that to instead of rendering an object onto the default java graphics rendering it on my own window, but does that not mean I will still have to invoke the .setVisible(true) function on a jframe, meaning there will be a second unused window active?

What I actually want to do is make a simple rendering engine which has a similar setup as the Graphics class. I'm far too lazy to make a complex widget library to be honest hahah.

Comment: The problem is that building a rendering engine is not simple and requires platform specific implementations. Therefore I think it would be a better idea to either extend swing and add the features that you like or extend and build on the graphics class

Comment: My plan was indeed to use something like the graphics class as an interface, however I'm still uncertain as to how I get the JFrame to render on this custom graphics class. Ps. LWJGL is a cross-platform graphics library which should remove the inconvenience of platform specific features.

Comment: Here is example of some renderers(look&feel themes): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459758/how-to-use-windows-xp-theme-in-java-swing-applications/44089825#44089825